# Parse past all occurrences of a delimiter

Tags: bash, parsing, delimiter, backslash

I am new to Bash, but hoping this is simple to do.  I have the following couple lines of code:

```
LOCATION='C:\\proj\\myproject\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\chromedriver_2.29.exe'
FILENAME=${LOCATION}
```

How do I parse past all the backslashes, go to the end of the path, extract the file name and assign it to `$FILENAME` (in this case 'chromedriver_2.29.exe') ?

Comment: As an aside: It is better not to use all-uppercase shell variable names in order to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
FILENAME=${LOCATION##*'\\'}
```

See details on parameter expansion in Bash [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal).